# Cannot install angular-cache to my ionic project

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I tried to create a new project using the following command

```
ionic start BlankApp blank
```

to create a blank app from Blank templates
Next I run

```
bower install --save angular-cache
```

and the installing process stop at

```
bower angular#>=1.x           validate 1.5.6 against https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#>=1.x
```

So I tried using

```
npm install --save angular-cache
```

It create a folder named "node_modules" and the following error

```
ionic-project@1.1.1 /Users/Thipok/Desktop/ProjectSth/Cache-Local
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY angular@>=1.x <2
└── angular-cache@4.6.0 

npm WARN angular-cache@4.6.0 requires a peer of angular@>=1.x <2 but none was installed.
npm WARN ionic-project@1.1.1 No repository field.
npm WARN ionic-project@1.1.1 No license field.
```

I also tried to install cordova-plugin-wkwebview and failed but that is not the question here.

Comment: try this `npm install angular`  & `<script src="/node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>` in your index.html and `bower install angular` and `<script src="/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>` here is the blog i found after a quick search https://github.com/angular/bower-angular

Comment: using `bower install angular` the terminal process stop at `bower angular#*               validate 1.5.6 against https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#*` again as above. And installing angular using npm caused a warning in javascript console `WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.`

Comment: first update your ionic and all other things like cordova node npm ..etc  and then try it

Comment: Still yeild the same result

Comment: `WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once` this error occurs because you have mentioned more then one time your angular in your code so remove this angular or check this one `<script src="/node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>` Or `require('angular') ` from your code.

Comment: Still cannot install angular-cache

Comment: And the warning is still there. I think it because ionic already have `angularjs` in their `ionic.bundle.js` file. But if I remove `ionic.bundle.js` from index.html. I wouldn't be able to run ionic in my app.

Comment: yes ofcourse thats what i am  trying to say in my previous comment when you create your ionic project by default every thing is add in your index.html page you should check there

Comment: no need to remove your ionic.bundle.js and you should not remove it

Comment: try this command `bower install` and then try to install angular catch

Comment: I got the following error `bower ECMDERR       Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads git://github.com/driftyco/ionic-bower.git", exit code of #128 fatal: read error: Connection reset by peer`